# What is a typical example for playing video files of any type with Allegro library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, allegro, allegro5, msvc12

I want to play a video of some type/format in my c++ program, i have installed Allegro 4.2.2 and Allegro5 along with both MSVC10 and MSVC13, i don't want to use any other library as they are a bit difficult to understand, if there is an easier way then tell me else tell me how to accomplish this task with Allegro?

Answer (score 3):

As of Allegro5.1, there is a [video
addon](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/video.html) (it is not available in
5.0).

There is an
[example](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/blob/5.1/examples/ex_video.c)
included in the allegro5 repository demonstrating how to use it.

The general gist is:

1. Invoke `al_init_video_addon`
2. Open the video with `al_open_video`
3. Start the video with `al_start_video`
4. Get the current frame as a bitmap with `al_get_video_frame`
5. Draw that bitmap with the usual bitmap drawing functions (`al_draw_*_bitmap`)

Repeat 4-5 during your game loop, then invoke `al_close_video` when you are done.

In the example they use `al_draw_scaled_bitmap` to scale the bitmap to the
screen; just take a look at the comments.

Note that you will need to link the video addon when linking your program
(`-lallegro_video`).

Comment: Also, if you need more info, there is the Allegro.cc forum.

Comment: the example is too much complex, i just want to play a video without giving the user any control over it.

Comment: Well... That's as simple as it gets. There is no magic al_play_full_video() function. You need to get each frame and display it individually. That's how video works internally on almost every other platform I think

Comment: how to get the allegro 5.1, I have allegro 5.1.9 which doesn't have the header file "allegro_video.h" required to play the videos.

Comment: 5.1.9 should have `allegro_video.h`, I just checked it out from the [git repo](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5)